# How to convert MS WORD underlined text to Excel in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, excel, ms-word

I have a word file which has an underlined text. I want to convert the text to an Excel sheet.

Comment: Could you please share what you have already tried in order to do it? I recommend you reading our [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: i wanted to ask about my problem, and when i was looking for it i found the solution so i shared it here because if someone mombers are in the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the answer. Hope this will help.

```
Private Sub underlined()

    With Me.OpenFileDialog1
        If .ShowDialog = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then

            Dim objWordApp As Word.Application
            objWordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
            objWordApp.Visible = True
            Dim objDoc As Word.Document = objWordApp.Documents.Open(.FileName)
            Dim under As Range
            Dim list_underline As New List(Of String)

            under = objDoc.Content
            With under.Find
                .Text = ""
                .Forward = True
                .Format = True
                .MatchCase = True
                .MatchWholeWord = False
                .MatchWildcards = True
                .MatchSoundsLike = False
                .MatchAllWordForms = False
                .MatchPhrase = False
                .Replacement.Text = ""
                .Font.Underline = WdUnderline.wdUnderlineSingle
                .Wrap = WdFindWrap.wdFindStop
            End With

            under.Find.Execute()
            While under.Find.Found


                under.Select()
                'under.Comments.Add(under, "Underlined Trouvé = " & under.Text)
                list_underline.Add(under.Text)

                under.Find.Execute()

            End While

            With Me.SaveFileDialog1
                If .ShowDialog = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
                    Dim app As New Excel.Application
                    Dim workbook As Excel.Workbook
                    Dim sheet As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet

                    workbook = app.Workbooks.Add()
                    workbook.Sheets.Select()
                    sheet = workbook.Sheets("Feuil1")
                    sheet.Cells(1, 1) = "Intitulée"
                    For i As Integer = 0 To list_underline.Count - 1

                        sheet.Cells(i + 2, 1) = list_underline(i)

                    Next

                    sheet.SaveAs(.FileName)
                    workbook.Close()
                    app.Quit()

                    releaseObject(app)
                    releaseObject(workbook)
                    releaseObject(sheet)
                    MsgBox("good job")
                End If

            End With

        End If

    End With

End Sub
```